# Python ObjectId(stringFromJson) object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, socket.io

I use nodeJS client to send a JSON to a socketIO server, but on the server console I get the following error:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

that is triggered by the `ObjectId(userId)` in the `emergency_doc = { 'user_id' : ObjectId(userId), ...}`  line from the server
client side code (nodejs)

```
var io = require('socket.io-client');
var socket = io.connect(SERVER_ADDRESS);

socket.on('connect', () => {
  socket.emit(
    'create_premium_emergency',
    JSON.stringify({id: '061698f991f4255a5dcdbc1e', location: 'H32G+C8'}),
  );
});
```

server side code (python)

```
@socketio.on('create_premium_emergency')
def create_premium_emergency(not_json):
    content = json.loads(not_json)
    userId = content["id"]
    location = content["location"]
    now = datetime.now()
#    db = get_db()
    user = get_user(userId)
    x = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for _ in range(5))

    emergency_doc = { 'user_id' : ObjectId(userId), 'cod': x,'initial_location' : location, 'is_premium': True,'citizen_dispatch': user["citizen_dispatch"], 'is_accepted': False, 'statuses': [{'status': "Created",'start_date': now }], 'is_closed': False, 'date_created': now}
    db.sos_emergencies.insert_one(emergency_doc),
```